# Download file stops before it reaches the real size in my Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration, hosting

I use a plugin called wp-client in my Wordpress website to help me to create a partner portal but when I try to download a big file ( 500 MB ), It doesn't complete the real size of the file and its size varies depending on internet speed to reach a specific size. I try to change PHP parameters in hosting but the issues still the same.

**This is the configuration I used:**

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 0
memory_limit = 640M
post_max_size = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 1500M
```

Comment: I found the problem it is with the Goddady hosting, I tried downloading from Bluehost and it works fine, with the same configuration

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you.

```
<?php
function sendHeaders($file, $type, $name=NULL)
{
    if (empty($name))
    {
        $name = basename($file);
    }
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'";');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
}

$file = '/path/to/files/photo.jpg';
if (is_file($file))
{
    sendHeaders($file, 'image/jpeg', 'My picture.jpg');
    $chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
    $handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your configurations in wp-config.php file instead of hosting.

Comment: I put this code in php.ini on the root of the website, but the problem still the same.

Comment: have you put it in wp-config.php file.?